# Help with Arduino sleep and watchdog timer interrupt

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, atmega328, sleep, watchdog

I want to use Arduino's sleep and wakeup functionality but have hit a roadblock and can't seem to get past it. As I am just prototyping for a final system, I cannot use the LowPower library to implement the functionality so I am doing it barebones. I am able to put the Arduino to sleep just fine, the main problem is with the watchdog timer. I have or I think I have configured it for a 8 sec interrupt to wake the Arduino back up from sleep but Arduino comes out of the sleep just as it enters it without any delay.
The code is

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>

void goToSleep();
void setupWDT();
void stopWDT();

ISR(WDT_vect) {
  sleep_disable(); // wake up the Arduino
}

void setup() {
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);

  stopWDT();

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Uno is in setup funtion.");

  bool ledState = 0;
  while(millis()<3000){
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, ledState);
    ledState = !ledState;
    delay(500);
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Uno is awake.");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Going to sleep...");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  delay(100);

  setupWDT();
  goToSleep();
  stopWDT();
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
}

void goToSleep() {
  ADCSRA &= ~(1<<ADEN); // disable ADC
  sleep_mode(); // put the Arduino to sleep
}

void setupWDT() {
  cli();
  WDTCSR |= (1 << WDCE);
  WDTCSR &= ~(1 << WDE);
  WDTCSR |= (1 << WDCE) | (1 << WDIE) | (1 << WDP3) | (1 << WDP0); // configured for 8 sec delay interrupt
  sei();
}

void stopWDT() {
  cli();
  MCUSR &= ~(1 << WDRF); // clear reset flag
  WDTCSR |= (1 << WDCE);
  WDTCSR &= ~(1<<WDE);
  WDTCSR = 0x00; // stop WDT
  sei();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
void setupWDT() {
  cli();
  WDTCSR |= (1 << WDCE);
  WDTCSR &= ~(1 << WDE);
  WDTCSR |= (1 << WDCE) | (1 << WDIE) | (1 << WDP3) | (1 << WDP0); // configured for 8 sec delay interrupt
  sei();
}
```

to:

```
void setupWDT() {
  cli();
  WDTCSR = (1 << WDCE) | (1 << WDE) ;
  WDTCSR = (1 << WDCE) | (1 << WDIE) | (1 << WDP3) | (1 << WDP0); // configured for 8 sec delay interrupt  
  sei();
}
```

It appears that your construct violates the 4 clock cycle window that the WDCE Watchdog Change Enable bit allows for updates to the WDE bit.